# Adding constraints to UITextField programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nslayoutconstraint

I am learning auto layout without using StoryBoard. I have given four constraints of trailing, leading, top and bottom.

**Code:**

```
UITextField *searchBarTF=[[UITextField alloc]init];  
[searchBarTF setText:@"is it coming?"];
[views addSubview:searchBarTF];

[views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBarTF attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:views attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:30]];

[views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBarTF attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:views attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:30]];

[views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBarTF attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:views attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:30]];

[views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBarTF attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:views attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:230]];
```

TextField is not appearing on screen.

**Error:**

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
```

Comment: could you please share the list that you got in error. Meanwhile just setTranslateAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO for searchBarTF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just forget this little piece of code:.

```
[searchBarTF setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

By default, this is `True`. So your constraints are conflicting with Autoresizing constraints.

The above line will disable auto resizing of your text field and it will apply your defined constraints.